# mod-proxy by query string to load balancer

Tags: mod-proxy

Given a balancer which currently proxies all requests:

```
<Proxy balancer://java-app>
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    BalancerMember https://java1:8443 route=java-app1
    BalancerMember https://java2:8443 route=java-app1
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass / balancer://java-app/ stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On
```

I need to modify it so that:
When the query string contains parameter p1
Then It should proxy to the balancer
Otherwise it should not proxy

mod-proxy cannot be used for this use case. We need to use mod-rewrite bu I can't figure how to achieve this goal effectively.

Thanks in advance,
- Nestor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing. A rewrite condition triggers the rewrite rule to pass through all requests containing the parameter p1 in the query string to the /restless endpoint. This endpoint does not exist in the server but it is just used to balance the request via the Proxy:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*p1=.*$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /restless$1 [PT] 

<Proxy balancer://java-app>
    ProxySet lbmethod=bybusyness
    BalancerMember https://java1:8443 route=java-app1
    BalancerMember https://java2:8443 route=java-app1
</Proxy>
```

ProxyPass /restless balancer://krfs-app stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite to proxy to a balancer configuration by using something like `RewriteRule (.*) balancer://java-app/$1 [P]`

Comment: Thanks bodgit, the question is if you can still specify parameters for that balancer like to use sticky session?

Comment: You can set them with the `ProxySet` directive at the same time as the `lbmethod` that you're already doing.